# Create a folder with DateTime as folder name

Tags: r, datetime

I am trying to create a folder with system date and time as folder name using the following command

```
dir.create(file.path(systempath, 'format(Sys.time(), "%F %R")'))
```

It is running but not creating the folder.

Comment: You can't create a folder that contains `:` in its name. `dir.create(file.path(systempath, format(Sys.time(), "%F %H-%M")))` would work.

Comment: this solution is not working

Comment: Yet you posted it as your own solution, nice job there.

Answer (score 0):

It's creating the desired folder using:

```
dir.create(file.path(systempath, format(Sys.time(), "%F %H-%M")))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
dir.create(file.path(systempath, 'format(Sys.time(), "%F %R")'), recursive=FALSE)
```